# VIM autoindent doesn't work properly

Tags: vim, vim7.3

In VIM when I type `gg=G` to auto indent the whole code, everything gets indented correctly except the lines  with the following structure:

```
$my_arr = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
)
```

I have set *shiftwidth* and *tabstop* to 2, but it indents the array elements by 4 spaces. Why?

Comment: filetype, indent settings (`autoindent`, `smartindent`, `indentexpr`), Vim version?

Comment: filetype = php/
vim version = 7.3/
smartindent and autoindent are set

Comment: try :set equalprg? to see what is actually run when you hit =. If this is non-blank, you may have to configure/change that program.

Comment: That is how vim indents unfinished statements that continue on the next row. If you have a = on one row and b; on the next it will be indented the same way. Try searching in `:h indent.txt` for how to change that.

Comment: Is `cinoptions` set? I can't reproduce this behaviour with only the settings you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You never answered the question about `'indentexpr'`.  Probably that means it is empty.  Try

```
:set indentexpr=GetPhpIndent()
```

This should be set automatically if you have

```
:filetype plugin indent on
```

in your vimrc file.  I get that indirectly from

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

See

```
:help :filetype
:help :filetype-indent-on
:help php-indent
```